# chrome lag on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

I'm using ubuntu 20.04. I installed chrome but it's so bad. When I use it, I feel like 5 fps. It's so lag. That doesn't happen on Firefox. How can I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you disable hardware acceleration (in Chrome) and then restart the browser? The option is in your settings.

Comment: @KGIII Great. Thank you so much. <3